# Why After a while my program is force closed?

Tags: android, forceclose, reminders

My app work as well, But after 12 or 24 hours does not work because the program has been closed by the operating system.

How can I prevent the closure of the program by the operating system?

My phone model: `Huawei G620S-L02`

I am set alarm like this:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);        
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this.mContext, AlarmReciever.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.mContext, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 25 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```

and this is `AlarmReciever`:

```
    public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {                
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                .setTicker(sticker)
                .setContentTitle("title") // title for notification
                .setContentText("text)   // message for notification
                .setAutoCancel(true)    // clear notification after click
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 500)
                .setShowWhen(false);               

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and my `Manifest` is:

```
<receiver
android:name=".AlarmReciever"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Short answer you can't. Try to use AlarmManager,BroadcastReceiver and Services

Comment: @RaduIonescu I am used AlarmManager,BroadcastReceiver,Services and everythings you think!, but when my app has force close ,dont worked!.my app worked perfectlly But after 12 or 24 hours does not work because the program has been closed by the operating system.

Comment: You should then include this information in your post. Add a little more details of what you are using and maybe code on how you manage this remainder

Comment: Instead of vote down please guide me.

Comment: I did not down vote you and I am trying to help you :)

Comment: @RaduIonescu I put my codes, please see my edit above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103301/discussion-between-javadaskari-and-radu-ionescu).

Comment: Do you have a WAKE_LOCK permission in your manifest?

Comment: Check the logcat. You could see more information here.

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás not show  anything in logcat.android will be close programs that do nothing work for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some devices(like HUAWEI), Your app must be checked in Protected apps:

Go to Settings => Protected apps => checked your apps